# Coova-Chilli 1.3.0 build fails for Ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: build, openssl, ubuntu-14.04, radius, coovachilli

Followed the directions from Coova-Chilli distribution build.

```
wget https://coova.github.io/coova-chilli/coova-chilli-1.3.0.tar.gz
tar xzf coova-chilli-1.3.0.tar.gz
cd coova-chilli-1.3.0/
debuild -b
```

and the results are the following error.

```
...........Error Section................

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libssl.a(s23_srvr.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against   
`.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/libssl.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
libtool: install: error: relink `libchilli.la' with the above command before   
installing it
make[4]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/download/coova-chilli-1.3.0/src'
make[3]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/download/coova-chilli-1.3.0/src'
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/download/coova-chilli-1.3.0/src'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/download/coova-chilli-1.3.0'
make: *** [install] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit 
status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1364:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc -b failed
```

I initially thought maybe openssl was not a recent enough version.  None of the other applications had that problem.  So I removed openssl package, built and installed it from source.  The latest version is openssl 1.0.2e.  I retested radius server after ripping up and rebuilding openssl and all is surprisingly still working fine.

I tried to compile coova-chilli again and also 1.2.9 as well but received the same error.  libssl.a is present in that location.

Any thoughts on how best to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions for Debian/Ubuntu on Coova-Chilli were not correct for Ubuntu.

```
wget https://coova.github.io/coova-chilli/coova-chilli-1.3.0.tar.gz
tar xzf coova-chilli-1.3.0.tar.gz
cd coova-chilli-1.3.0/ 
./configure --prefix= --enable-miniportal (or whatever flags you want)
make 
sudo make install
update-rc.d chilli defaults
```

Reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/CoovaChilli